# How to cache variable inside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's say I have a long list of items.

```
this.items = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}, ...]; // 2000 items
```

And I want to display them without heavy-loading browser.
My template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
  <span>{{ ::item.id }}</span>
</div>
```

It provides only one watcher for `items` array and my list scrolls fast enough.
But let's say I want two different modes: one, that displays ids and other, that displays names.

In Controller:

`this.modeId = true;`

In template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
  <span ng-if="$cltr.modeId">{{ ::item.id }}</span>
  <span ng-if="!$cltr.modeId">{{ ::item.name }}</span>
</div>
```

Aaaaaand I have 4001 watcher. Browsers crushing, I'm crying.
Why angular not caching `$ctrl.modeId`, it is the same variable across entire template, why it needs to watch for that one damn variable 4000 times.

Is there any workarounds?

PS. I can't make it one-time binding, because somewhere I have a button, that switches modes. Yep, I can wrap whole `ng-repeat` in `<div ng-if="$ctrl.modeId">...</div>`, but rendering 2000 every time mode switches consumes so much resources.

Comment: usually ng-show is better for you atleast better than ng-if

Comment: @VinodLouis yep, you are right, but it doesn't solve watchers problem

Comment: Is template that simple? You can try `<div ng-switch="$cltr.modeId" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
  <span ng-switch-when="true">{{ ::item.id }}</span>
  <span ng-switch-when="false">{{ ::item.name }}</span>
</div>`

Comment: @Satpal well, not that, but it's simple. It's list component, part of page. One item in list consists of time, title, icon, another icon, text. So my template ~ 25 rows

Comment: @Satpal using ng-switch reduces watchers in a half. Thanks for pointing it out, but it's not enough. Actually, I think, I should create DOM only directive, that will be hiding-showing something in entire list like  `$('.list .list-item .mode-id ').show()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template caching feature of Angularjs as follows.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
  <span>{{ ::item.id }}</span>
  </div>
</script>
```

To retrieve the template later, simply use it in your component:

```
myApp.component('myComponent', {
   templateUrl: 'templateId.html'
});
```

or get it via the $templateCache service:

```
$templateCache.get('templateId.html')
```

Comment: It is similar to wrapping list in div. Inserting big DOM node is not simple for poor browsers

Comment: @vedmaque My suggestion is to you that never populate or show whole data on UI / browser if your records are increasing  as you said currently you have a  2000 records, you can use lazy load or pagination functionality by slot of limited records for example 20 or 50 in one attempt.

Comment: yes, I totally agree with you. It's really bad practice to show a whole list of many items. But the question is more about angular behavior, when it watches for variables.